# Flutter web on Android Chrome Desktop mode, Scales

Tags: flutter

I have a simple flutter web application that displays very well on Computer , browsers and mobile browsers, but when I turn android chrome browser to desktop mode, it becomes weird.

Android Chrome normal:
[normal mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRpA8.jpg)

Android Chrome Desktop mode:
[desktop mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPO7k.jpg)

pobspec.yaml

```
name: flutterapp
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

This is the main application class, which is just the default generated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Homepage, which I only added extra bottom navigation bar and container at the center, to what flutter generated.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      ),
        body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              color: Colors.brown
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: "Home"
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: "Search"
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: "Profile"
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

I used the code bellow to run the flutter web application.

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 5000 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 --web-renderer canvaskit
```